# Autocompletion not working in Android Studio Arctic Fox inside buildSrc

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am writing a custom plugin inside `buildSrc` using Android Studio Arctic Fox installed by brew. After some tests, there is a problem with the autocompletion of imports. It works inside `app/build.gradle.kts` that I can do `import com.android.build.api.dsl.*`, but inside `buildSrc` this raised `Unresolved reference` on android namespace.

The root `build.gradle.kts`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        extra["kotlin_version"] = "1.4.32"

        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2")
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "1.4.32"))

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

`build.gradle.kts` under buildSrc:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.31"
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
        apiVersion = "1.4"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2")
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.0.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32")
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    gradleApi()
}
```

`build.gradle.kts` under `app`:

```
import com.example.pythonLibs

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    id("com.example.plugin")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 30
    ndkVersion = "23.0.7599858"

    sourceSets {
        getByName("main") {
            pythonLibs {
                srcDir("src/main/pythonLibs")
            }
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.embedpythontest"
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 30
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // consumerProguardFiles = [file("consumer-rules.pro")]
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                //arguments("-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared")
                //cppFlags("")
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path = file("src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt")
            version = "3.21.3"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_11)
        targetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_11)
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
        apiVersion = "1.4"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
}
```

in all files under `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/**`, when doing `import com.android.build.api.dsl.*`, a problem shown but build project is ok. But if I do import inside `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, it won't be compiled. But the same thing could be done inside `app/build.gradle.kts`.

Why Android Studio cannot find the class?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by not being familiar with the dependencies in Gradle. After changing the `dependncy` block to:

```
dependencies {
   implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.0.2")
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    gradleApi()
}
```

which copied from [here](https://github.com/android/gradle-recipes/blob/agp-7.0/BuildSrc/addBuildTypeUsingDslFinalize/buildSrc/build.gradle.kts) that would solve the problem.

Comment: I only added gradleApi and worked. Thanks a lotf